# Measure time of execution in F#

Tags: f#, time, measure

Please post code for displaying time in F#. I noticed that you can measure it from F# interactive with #time directive, but I don't know how to execute program from FSI

Thanks

Comment: At the time of writing, this wasn't available, but don't use stopwatch and the like, it's extremely flawed. Instead, use Benchmarkdotnet for proper performance measuring, and a profiler.

Answer (score 58):

I would just use the .NET Stopwatch class.

```
let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
...
stopWatch.Stop()
printfn "%f" stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: But if you're in FSI (F# Interactive REPL), you get more detailed information (CPU time, Real time, GC info). Adding [PrivateEye](http://www.privateeye.io/#) gives even full profiling info from FSI, no extra programming needed.

Comment: @Abel Do you happen to know if PrivateEye is still available somewhere? The website is unfortunately defunct. I even contacted one of the authors, and he told me I should still be able to find the code somewhere, but then contact broke of... :(

Comment: @sebhofer, I don't know. I only use Benchmarkdotnet nowadays, gives much info, and takes care of warmup time, averages, outliers, graphs etc etc. It's used for improving the runtime itself, it's pretty darn stable.

Comment: When I use this with AOT in 8.0-preview5, I get
Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl+Specializations`3[System.IO.TextWriter,Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit,Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit].CaptureFinal1[System.Int32](Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl+Step[])' is missing native code. MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod() is not compatible with AOT compilation. Inspect and fix AOT related warnings that were generated when the app was published. For more information see https://aka.ms/nativeaot-compatibility

Answer (score 34):

From msdn:

> By itself, **#time** toggles whether to display performance information.
>   When it is enabled, F# Interactive measures real time, CPU time, and
>   garbage collection information for each section of code that is
>   interpreted and executed.

So to test you function you have to open F# interactive console and execute your function in it (one way to do it is to select your function, right click and chose Execute in Interactive)
Then make a call to your function in Interactive like that for example:

// define your function first either in interactive console or in your document:

```
let square x = x * x

// in interactive
#time
square 10
#time
```

You will see how much of real time and CPU time were spent on computation and a bit of information from garbage collector

Answer (score 22):

Check out the timer function in the [F Sharp Programming wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Higher_Order_Functions#A_Timer_Function). It is defined like this:

```
let duration f = 
    let timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    timer.Start()
    let returnValue = f()
    printfn "Elapsed Time: %i" timer.ElapsedMilliseconds
    returnValue
```

Whilst being used like this:

```
let sample() = System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2)

duration ( fun() -> sample() )
// or
duration sample
```

Comment: they are using DateTime.Now to measure time in their function, that's hardly a replacement for the Stopwatch timer.

Comment: @BrokenGlass wiki was updated a while back to use stopwatch.  Included here for reference

Answer (score 1):

You could also create custom computation expression to hide actual measuring logic, e.g.:

```
timer {
   // your code goes here
}
```

See more examples here: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-bind/