# Memory analysis in F#

Tags: f#, analysis

I recently started learning F#. Are there any tools available for perform Dynamic analysis in F# . I want to monitor the memory leaks which might creep in when i make C calls from F# application.

Comment: You may also find this at:
[Stack OverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10045591/9832710)

Comment: there are many memory profilers for .net, `dotMemory` from  JetBrains, or the built-in profiling tools in `Visual Studio`.

Comment: Do you mean P/Invoke calls ?